# calling an action on clicking NSPopupButton

Tags: cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopupButton that displays a drop down menu when clicked. This menu is populated from an NSArray. Now if I click on one of the items in the drop down Menu, I can select it and determine what is selected etc.
What I want to do is when the user clicks on the NSpopupbutton, update the drop down menu and then have the user pick one of the items. 
I am having trouble finding how to call a IBAction method when I simply select the drop down menu ( not clicking any one item in it). The clicking of an item in the menu results in an IBAction, but I want just the clicking of the down arrow in the NSPopupButton to trigger an action. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The `NSPopupButton` sends an `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` when clicked. Have your controller object listen for that notification and respond by updating the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer worked, though now it's called NSPopUpButton.willPopUpNotification

In Swift 4.x, my code looked like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                 selector: #selector(dropdownMenuOpened),
                 name: NSPopUpButton.willPopUpNotification,
                 object: nil)
```